# How can I add more space in anychart?

Tags: anychart

I have a simple question for anychart. My client asked me to create a chart with special extra space on the right side of stock chart plot.

For example, we have a daily data from 2018-09-01 to 2018-09-30. Anychart did well for its function to draw candlesticks for whole space. However, my client would like to draw or give some labels on the chart, and doesn't want to make them interfere with the chart series. So they would like to add extra space on the right of the plot.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the current version of AnyChart 8.4.0 doesn't provide an out-of-the-box method to extend the xScale with empty space or gap. We are often asked about this feature and now our dev team is working on it. In the next releases, this feature will become available and we will notify you about it. As a temporary workaround, you can add empty points at the end of dataTable to extend the xScale. For details, please, check the sample provided in the comment below.

Comment: The sample which describes how to add empty points - https://playground.anychart.com/UFD6Nob1

Answer (score 0):

we are glad to inform you that we have released 8.4.2 update which brings many fixes and improvements. This update also includes an opportunity to add gaps in the Stock chart. You can achieve that like this:
`chart.xScale().maximumGap({intervalsCount: 4, unitType: 'week', unitCount: 1});`
For details, check the sample in the comment below.